# Top Bar and Login Screen Low Resolution

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, login-screen, top-bar

I have a brand new install of 20.04. When I log into the OS, the login screen is a low resolution (something like 800x600, but I am not 100% sure what it is). Then once I log in, everything is normal, except for the top bar which keeps its low resolution.

If I go into settings and change the scaling then revert, everything goes back to how it should look.

What can I do to fix this?

I have tried editing `/etc/default/grub` to include

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

But that didn't seem to have any effect.

Display driver:
Nvidia Drivers 440.100

Computer: Dell Precision 7530

Also, something to note, when I log in, the computer shows the Dell logo on screen until the desktop loads.

Comment: You mention grub settings (which impact `grub` only), the login/greeter screen is `gdm3` by default on Ubuntu desktop (sort of a very reduced subset of GNOME, but incapable of using all GNOME settings until GNOME has started). The dell logo you're talking about sounds like a `plymouth` screen (which can be changed; the current one is intended to highlight the OEM manufacturer; as OEMs like that). I don't use `gdm3` so can't help with its configuration, but it's not your only choice (if you're otherwise happy with it, stick with it & wait for help, or search for how to configure it yourself)

Comment: @guiverc you're a genius. Knowing that was gdm3 not grub gave me an idea. I simply ran `sudo apt purge gdm3` and then rebooted, ran `apt install gdm3` in the root shell, rebooted again, and it worked! Feel free to copy and put as an answer for some sweet sweet points. I appreciate your knowledge and input! Thank you!

Comment: You solved it, so well done.  Feel free to write your own answer, and you'll get the *rep* boost if it's accepted (*ie. unless you decide to credit another answer; I won't write one*).  You can thank me (by ref.) there if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was to uninstall and reinstall gdm3
I ran `sudo apt purge gdm3`, rebooted into recovery mode, ran `apt install gdm3` from the root terminal then rebooted again. The issue was solved.

Big thanks to @guiverc for pointing out that the issue was with gdm3 not grub